# Change activity and reset a gridview on click

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm working on building a chess app and need help with ending the game.

Upon clicking an end game button, I'd like to return to the main screen and reset the gameActivity which holds the game board. The board is a gridview that holds images of chess pieces.

Some things I have tried:

```
Intent intent = getIntent()
finish()
startActivity(intent)
```

I realize that this would just restart the activity and now return to the main activity. But even with this the grid view is retained and pieces are not reset.

```
pieceGrid.setAdapter(new PieceAdapter());
pieceAdapter = new(PieceAdapter(context));
finish();
```

This finishes the activity and returns to the main activity, but upon starting a new game the pieces remain in the spots that they were previously in. I think I am misunderstanding how the Adapter and context act together but cannot piece it together. Below is my PieceAdapter class.

### PieceAdapter.java

```
public class PieceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public PieceAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new MyImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        imageView = (MyImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
// references to our images
public static Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.blackrook, R.drawable.blackknight, R.drawable.blackbishop, R.drawable.blackqueen, R.drawable.blackking, R.drawable.blackbishop, R.drawable.blackknight, R.drawable.blackrook,
        R.drawable.blackpawn, R.drawable.blackpawn, R.drawable.blackpawn, R.drawable.blackpawn, R.drawable.blackpawn, R.drawable.blackpawn, R.drawable.blackpawn, R.drawable.blackpawn,
        R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare,
        R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare,
        R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare,
        R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare, R.drawable.emptysquare,
        R.drawable.whitepawn, R.drawable.whitepawn, R.drawable.whitepawn, R.drawable.whitepawn, R.drawable.whitepawn, R.drawable.whitepawn, R.drawable.whitepawn, R.drawable.whitepawn,
        R.drawable.whiterook, R.drawable.whiteknight, R.drawable.whitebishop, R.drawable.whitequeen, R.drawable.whiteking, R.drawable.whitebishop, R.drawable.whiteknight, R.drawable.whiterook
};
```

Apologies if I am being unclear. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like sequential calls to finish() and then straight away to startActivity(intent) just do nothing.

Try

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.class);
i.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: No luck :/. The best I can do right now is write something up to restore the image ID's in the adapter but even that is seeing some issues.